# How to create application and workspace through script?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I created a workspace provision app, where is possible to create workspace without access to administration services. Now, I want to do the same for applications, to install application on workspace remotely on button click.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why would you do either? Self-provisioned workspaces can already be configured in APEX. Workspaces and apps can already be exported and installed as SQL scripts, or imported through the APEX UI. What is the point of either app, except to circumvent normal security and/or Oracle-supported APIs?

Comment: @pmdba With app I don't need access to administration services to create workspace. How I can install app through script on autonomous DB?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of this tutorial

https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2018/08/scripting-service-creation-in-oracle.html

But you must need to have sys privileges

Answer (score 0):

You can create the workspace and application by running the script file.
Try to review mentioned link.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-deploying-oracle-application-express-apex-applications-using-sqlcl-and-liquibase

Comment: How can it be used in a Autonomous database?